# Assigning unique identifier to consecutive sequences of binomial values in R

Tags: r, sequence, seq, run-length-encoding

I have a dataframe with column consisting of sequences of 0s and 1s. The 0s are not of interest but the 1s signify events occurring in a time series and the goal is to assign a unique value to each event. Simple integer values suffice. So in the code below 'x' is what I have and 'goal' is what I am after.

This seems so simple yet I don't quite know how to phrase the question on a help search...

What I have as a dataframe:

```
x <- c(rep(0,4),rep(1,5),rep(0,2),rep(1,4),rep(0,10),rep(1,3))

x <- data.frame(x)
```

What I want in the dataframe:

```
x$goal <- c(rep(0,4),rep(1,5),rep(0,2),rep(2,4),rep(0,10),rep(3,3))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is effectively a run-length encoding, with a slight-twist (of zero-izing `0`s).

While `data.table::rleid` does this well, if you are not already using that package, then we'll use

```r
my_rleid <- function(x) { yy <- rle(x); rep(seq_along(yy$lengths), yy$lengths); }
```

From here, we'll see

```r
x$out <- my_rleid(x$x)
x$out <- ifelse(x$x == 0, 0L, x$out)
x
#    x goal out
# 1  0    0   0
# 2  0    0   0
# 3  0    0   0
# 4  0    0   0
# 5  1    1   2
# 6  1    1   2
# 7  1    1   2
# 8  1    1   2
# 9  1    1   2
# 10 0    0   0
# 11 0    0   0
# 12 1    2   4
# 13 1    2   4
# 14 1    2   4
# 15 1    2   4
# 16 0    0   0
# 17 0    0   0
# 18 0    0   0
# 19 0    0   0
# 20 0    0   0
# 21 0    0   0
# 22 0    0   0
# 23 0    0   0
# 24 0    0   0
# 25 0    0   0
# 26 1    3   6
# 27 1    3   6
# 28 1    3   6
```

which is pretty close. If you need consecutive numbers (no gaps like above), then

```r
x$out <- match(x$out, sort(unique(x$out))) - (0 %in% x$out)
x
#    x goal out
# 1  0    0   0
# 2  0    0   0
# 3  0    0   0
# 4  0    0   0
# 5  1    1   1
# 6  1    1   1
# 7  1    1   1
# 8  1    1   1
# 9  1    1   1
# 10 0    0   0
# 11 0    0   0
# 12 1    2   2
# 13 1    2   2
# 14 1    2   2
# 15 1    2   2
# 16 0    0   0
# 17 0    0   0
# 18 0    0   0
# 19 0    0   0
# 20 0    0   0
# 21 0    0   0
# 22 0    0   0
# 23 0    0   0
# 24 0    0   0
# 25 0    0   0
# 26 1    3   3
# 27 1    3   3
# 28 1    3   3
```

The reason I chose to use `- (0 %in% x$out)` instead of a hard-coded `1` is that I wanted to guard against the possibility of there being no 0s in the data. Put differently, that `(0 %in% x$out)` resolves to `FALSE` or `TRUE`, which when subtracted from `integer`s, is coerced to `0L` or `1L`, respectively. The reason I need this: if there is a `0` in `$out`, then `match` will effectively be `match(0, 0:6)` which will return `1`. We want the `x == 0` matches to be `0L`, so we have to subtract one. Since the second argument (from `sort(unique(.))`) is always either 0-based (as here) or 1-based (no zeroes present in `x$x`), it's an easy adjustment.

If you are certain that this cannot be the case, *and* you don't like the `- (.)` I appended to `match(.)`, then you can change that to `match(.) - 1L`.

Comment: Wow, thanks! Works nicely and I appreciate the ability to do so using base commands.

Comment: You could also work only with the `rle` object: `r = rle(x != 0); r$values = cumsum(r$values) * r$values; inverse.rle(r)`